# How to put collection view and page view within one Scene

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a screen like below:

[image: screen]

But the problem is, pagedView requires my view controller to inherit from `UIPagedViewController`, while colleciton view requires inheriting from `UICollectionViewController`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `UIPagedViewController` or `UICollectionViewController` make it inherit from `UIViewController` ,  and inside say `loadView/ViewDidLoad` use

```
let pager = UIPagedViewController()
// then add it as a child vc and constraint it's view or set a frame
```

and

```
let collec = UICollectionView(///
// add to view and constraint also
```

The above should be instance vars also , so their delegates/dataSources being retained

Comment: So view controller can be container of other containers? I thought only some view controller can be containers, like Navigation View Controller

Comment: yes, they can simple search can give you a lot of examples on how to add child vcs

Comment: Two questions: 1. Can I make the UICollectionView inside a separate VC as well? (say, `UICollectionViewController` custom class ) 2. Can I set view constraints across DIFFERENT viewcontroller? e.g. pagedView under `UIPagedViewController` and collec under `UICollectionViewController`

Comment: 1- yes you can `UICollectionViewController ` is a vc that can be added as child also 2- when you add the 2 viewControllers constraint their views to whatever you need

Answer (score 1):

what about like this?

```
class MyPagedView: UIView, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    // add your pages
}

class MyCollectionView: UICollectionView, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    // add your collection view
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    lazy var myPages: MyPagedView = {
        let pages = MyPagedView()
        return pages
    }()
    lazy var myCV: MyCollectionView = {
        let cv = MyCollectionView()
        return cv
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(myPages)
        view.addSubview(myCV)
    }

}
```

**Of Course**, you will have to set your constraints according to your need.